# MySQL query extracting two pieces of information from table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table that keeps track of the scores of people playing my game

```
userID |  game_level |      date_of_attempt        |  score
   1           1          2014-02-07 19:29:00           2
   1           2          2014-02-08 19:00:00           0
   2           1          2014-03-03 11:11:04           4
  ...         ...                 ...                  ...
```

I am trying to write a query that, for a given user, will tell me their cumulative score for each `game_level` as well as they average of the last 20 scores they have obtained on a particular `game_level` (by sorting on `date_of_attempt`)

For example:

```
userID | game_level | sum of scores on game level |  average of last 20 level scores
   1         1                      26                              4.5
   1         2                     152                              13
```

Is it possible to do such a thing in a single query? I often need to perform the query for multiple game_levels, and I use a long subquery to work out which levels are needed which makes me think a single query would be better

Comment: Could you please post what you have tried so far (i.e. this "long subquery" you mentioned)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does not support analytic functions, so obtaining the average is trickier than it would be in some other RDBMS.  Here I use [user-defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/user-variables.html) to obtain the groupwise rank and then test on the result to average only over the 20 most recent records:

```
SELECT   userID, game_level, SUM(score), x.avg
FROM     my_table JOIN (
           SELECT   AVG(CASE WHEN (@rank := (CASE
                      WHEN t.userID     = @userID
                       AND t.game_level = @gamelevel
                      THEN @rank + 1
                      ELSE 0
                    END) < 20 THEN score END)   AS avg,
                    @userID     := userID     AS userID,
                    @game_level := game_level AS game_level
           FROM     my_table,
                    (SELECT @rank := @userID := @game_level := NULL) init
           ORDER BY userID, game_level, date_of_attempt DESC
         ) x USING (userID, game_level)
GROUP BY userID, game_level
```

See [How to select the first/least/max row per group in SQL](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) for further information.